# What visual studio project template should I use for a project consisting mainly of classes?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, architecture

This is how my solution looks like:

[image]

In "Application" I want to create an Application Service that will contain Unit Of Work operations.

In "Presentation" I will have an WCF service.

Does anyone know what type of project should an Application Service be?

Comment: This question could be rephrased as "I'm building a n-tier architecture. What goes in tier N?"

Comment: Uhm, no. "N-tier" means "multi-tier". "What goes into tier multi" makes no sense. What kind of project you should make depends on what you want it to do and how you will communicate with it. "Contain operations" makes it looks like you're just looking for a class library. See for example [Understand 3- Tier Architecture in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/662107/Understand-Tier-Architecture-in-Csharp).

Comment: Ok, I'm confused now :)

Comment: @CodeCaster read the question.

Comment: @Tom thanks for assuming I didn't. I'm not sure what you're trying to point out.

Comment: @CodeCaster perhaps it's a language/humor thing, but my comment was meant to be an observation that the OP sounded like they had read somewhere they needed to define a tier (called Application in this case but it could have been called "RainingPianos", "Tier 3", or anything else, hence the Tier-N in my comment - this being shorthand for "the tier that I have been told I need") but didn't know what to put in it. I certainly didn't get straight away that they were in fact asking "what visual studio project project template should I use for a project consisting mainly of classes".

Comment: @Tom lol, thanks. Your comment makes sense now, sarcasm over text is hard, you know.

Comment: @CodeCaster, no it isn't ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CodeCaster commented, I was looking for Class Library